# Getting DHCP, Gateway IP and MAC address from diagram

Tags: networking, ip, cmd.exe

I found an interesting diagram(picture) today, that is asking to find out the missing IP(numbers).

I know It should be easy, but I can't make it.

What I have found is: 31(?1).194(?2).254(?3).x(?4 Have no clue how to get It). Don't know if the numbers I have are right.

Anybody here knows how to make It and can explain to dummy like me?

The Diagram:

[image]

Comment: Homework question?

Comment: Maybe It was. I dont know. I found it on internet. Btw It's summer... :)

Comment: For `?1` where did you get `.31`? I'm thinking it's `.0` based on the command `display dhcp relay server-address` from int `G0/0`. `?2` is correct. For `?3` I think it should be `.199` because when doing tracert from the laptop, the first hop is `192.168.0.199` which is it's default gateway. I'm equally as stumped for `?4`

Comment: As I remember you have to get an IP address when solved It. So I never saw an IP starting with 0, so I tought it may be .31 (GE0/2)

Comment: `?1` is looking for the address of the third octet from the DHCP server. By looking at the command `display dhcp relay server-address` int G0/0` has the address of `172.16.0.2`. That's where I got `.0`. I'm still not following your `.31`.

Comment: #1 the DHCP server: No good answer yet (somewhere in the range 172.6.0.1 till 172.6.0.254?).   Could be that 172.16.0.2 but not sure.    


#2  I see four connections on the router. Assuming GE0/1 is badly placed and belong somewhat more to the left it is the first hop off the local network. Which is 192.168.0.199

#3: laptop pings device not on localnet. First destination is the default gateway. Traceroute show 192.168.0.199 as the first hop. I agree the answer is .199   

#4: This puzzled me. We got 4 of the 6 numbers needed to identify the owner. ONly one I found is HP with B4:99:BA